# Exact meaning of sell as a going concern

Tags: word-usage

how do you interprete the sentence below

"He sold the cafe as a going concern."
Logically, shouldn't the above sentence be : he bought instead of sold ?
Do you understand bankrupcy  or anything negative from this sentence? Because when sth or somewhre is making profits , we won't sell it . 
And  above all, does  " going concern"  have negative aspect of  meaning whenever  this expression is used in a sentence.

Comment: Of course you can sell something which is making money, if you don't want to run the business any more: perhaps the seller wanted to retire, or emigrate. In fact a "going concern" is far more valuable than one which won't bring in a return on your investment.

Comment: There's no good reason to say that "logically it should be bought instead of sold". The existing owner sells the business as a going concern and the new owner buys it as a going concern, it depends which party to the deal you're talking about. The main thing about buying as a going concern is that the business makes money immediately. In fact one of the assets of the business is the existing customer base, reputation and supplier relationships which are paid for as "goodwill" which can often be the most valuable asset of the business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct to say "Because when sth or somewhre is making profits , we won't sell it". The expression 'going concern' is positive, and has a standard meaning in accounting, namely that the company is in good financial health.

> Going concern
>   noun   (Finance: Corporate)
>   A going concern is a business
>   that is not in danger of failing.

[Going concern (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/going-concern)

A going concern is a...

> ...currently operating business that is expected to continue to
>   function as such and remain viable in the foreseeable future.

[Going concern (Business Dictionary)](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/going-concern.html)

If I have a successful business, making a profit, and I am offered something valuable for it, such as a sum of money, or shares in one or more other companies, and that valuable thing will provide an income at least equal to the profits I expect to make from my business, then my reasons for refusing to sell will not be financial.

Comment: Eg.I want to retire to the Bahamas. Or take on a new challenge. Or my partner has died and I can't face running the business without her. etc.